# Если цикл не отработал, как вывести на экран

Tags: java, циклы

Решаю задачу - вывод на экран всех чисел из диапазона ... Если ни одно число не попадает в диапазон - вывести на экран "Ни одно число не попало в диапазон"

Код:

```
private static void taskSolution(int a, int b) {
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && (Math.ceil(Math.log10(i)) == 3 || Math.ceil(Math.log10(i)) == 5) && i % 13 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Собственно, не понимаю как вывести на экран, ели у меня по условию if не будет ни одного результата . Если я вставлю в цикл for  System.out.println("Ни одно число не попало в дианазон");, то мне много раз выведет этот sout. То есть так - не работает

```
private static void taskSolution(int a, int b) {
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && (Math.ceil(Math.log10(i)) == 3 || Math.ceil(Math.log10(i)) == 5) && i % 13 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            } else System.out.println("Нет подходящих ");
        }
    }
```

Если цикл не отработал, как вывести на экран что ни под одно условие if не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так - делаем переменную и сохраняем в ней информацию было ли хоть одно нужное число. Если нет, то выводим текст.

```
private static void taskSolution(int a, int b) {
     boolean a = true;
     for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
         if (i % 2 == 0 && (Math.ceil(Math.log10(i)) == 3 
               || Math.ceil(Math.log10(i)) == 5)
               && i % 13 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                a = false;
               } 
         }
     if (a) { System.out.println("Нет подходящих "); }
    }
```

PS. Не надо употреблять слова "цикл не отработал". Цикл - отработал!

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заодно я впервые увидел подобную конструкцию if (a), почитал про неё и теперь буду знать

Comment: ``if (a)`` на самом деле то же самое, что и, например, ``if (x < y)``, потому что ``a`` - булево значение, которым и является в конечно итоге ``x < y``, просто это не очевидно.